# SICP - exercise 1.7 better end test for square root approximation

Tags: lisp, scheme, numerical-methods, sicp

Here is [exercise 1.7 from SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/chapter1/node9.html):

> Exercise 1.7
>
> The `good-enough?` test used in computing square roots will not be very
>   effective for finding the square roots of very small numbers. Also, in
>   real computers, arithmetic operations are almost always performed with
>   limited precision. This makes our test inadequate for very large
>   numbers. Explain these statements, with examples showing how the test
>   fails for small and large numbers. An alternative strategy for
>   implementing `good-enough?` is to watch how guess changes from one
>   iteration to the next and to stop when the change is a very small
>   fraction of the guess. Design a square-root procedure that uses this
>   kind of end test. Does this work better for small and large numbers?

I believe "a very small fraction of the guess" means guess*a-very-small-number. I think it is working correctly. I haven't found any values that could fail the `good-enough?` test. Is there something wrong here I haven't discovered? Please review my code. How can I improve it?

```
(define (sqrt x)
  (sqrt-iter 1.0 x))

(define (sqrt-iter guess x)
  (if (good-enough? guess (improve guess x))
      guess
      (sqrt-iter (improve guess x) x)))

(define (improve guess x)
  (average guess (/ x guess)))

(define (average x y) 
  (/ (+ x y) 2))

(define (good-enough? guess next-guess)
  (< (abs (- guess next-guess)) (* guess 0.000000000000000000000000000001)))

(define (square x)
  (* x x))
```

Comment: Right now you're asking for equality to something like 30 decimal digits. That's a *lot* more than you typically need. If you loosen that requirement, you'll typically use fewer iterations, so you'll get your results faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `sqrt-iter`

1. You compute `(improve guess x)` *twice* - this is a waste.
2. You return `guess` instead of the improved guess, i.e., you return a worse approximation than you could.

E.g.:

```
(define (sqrt-iter guess x)
  (let ((next-guess (improve guess x)))
    (if (good-enough? guess next-guess)
        next-guess
        (sqrt-iter next-guess x))))
```

## `good-enough?`

1. `0.000000000000000000000000000001` is unreadable. `1d-30` is better.
2. `1d-30` is far too high precision. With such an epsilon, you might as well use `=` instead of `good-enough?` - the "oscillation between two adjacent floats" problem will be the same. Read up on [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon).
3. This number should actually be an argument to `sqrt`.
4. Adding a line break would make the function more readable.

Comment: "you return a worse approximation than you could." - how mutch worse could this be? Is it possible I didn't notice it because of the very high precision I used?

Comment: at most `1d-30` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With IEEE floating point numbers, the multiplication (* guess 1d-30) may underflow, leading to a 0.0 result. The test would have to be more sophisticated in a real program. Check out these links [Comparison of floating point numbers](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/) , [Correctly Rounded Decimal to Floating-Point Conversion](http://www.exploringbinary.com/topics/)

The precision should also depend on the kind of floating points. If you use ieee754 32-bit, then you have only 24-bit, less than 8 decimal significant digits. With 64-bit you have 53 bits, or a little less than 16 significant digits. [Is the most significant decimal digits precision that can be converted to binary and back to decimal without loss of significance 6 or 7.225?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688422/is-the-most-significant-decimal-digits-precision-that-can-be-converted-to-binary)

I don't have a production-level code for this exercise but I'd also like to see one.